# Isomorphism of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $F$ are called isomorphic if there exists a bijective homomorphism of linear spaces $T : V \longrightarrow W$

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subspaces of $V$. Prove that $(A + B)/B$ is isomorphic to $A/(A \cap B)$.

I do not really understand the meaning of $(A + B)/B$ is it modular? If so, how do you divide by a set? same with $A/(A \cap B)$.

Comment: What textbook are you using? I'm sure there was a definition before this question.

Comment: Sorry, it is "Two vector spaces V and W over a field F are called isomorphic if there exists a bijective homomorphism of linear spaces T : V → W."

Comment: think its from intro to linear algebra

Comment: There should also be a definition for $/$. Look for quotient spaces.

Comment: ...There are a lot of books named "intro to linear algebra", I imagine.

Comment: sorry...but the definition should be the standard quotient space definition?

Comment: Unless you tell us where the question comes from, we can only assume that the author is following standard definitions.

Answer (score 1):

This is about quotient spaces. You'll find the definition on [Wikipedia - Quotient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)).

What you're requested to prove is Theorem B for modules in [Wikipedia Isomorphism  theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).

For a proof, you can have a look at theorem 3.21 of this [Quotient module paper](http://qu.edu.iq/el/pluginfile.php/62594/mod_resource/content/0/Module%20Theory%20-%20Lecture%203.pdf). A vector space is a module!

Comment: thanks a lot would you mind explaining how the defined lienar map is surjective?

Comment: Proof is in the paper I provided theorem 3.21... I'm afraid you have to open it and read it.

Comment: sorry but i did read the proof and understood the second part of the kernel, but for the first part i dont really understand (the first pargaph or two liens)

Comment: By definition an element $y \in (M_1+M_2)/M_2$ can be written $m_1+m_2 + M_2$, with $m_1,m_2$ in $M_1,M_2$ respectively. But as $m_2+M_2 = M_2$, $m_1+m_2 + M_2 = m_1 +M_2$ proving that $\varphi$ is surjective as $\varphi(m_1) = y$.

Comment: okay that makes sense but why is by definition an element ∈(1+2)/2 can be written 1+2+2?  shouldn't it just be m1+m1? sorry if this sounds stupid

Comment: That's just the definition. May I suggest that you go back to the definition of a quotient space and make some exercises around it? I'm sure it will hep you.

Comment: thank you i will do that; but is quotient space different from quotient group?

Comment: i understand that quotient space is a specific type of quotient group but how does the quotient group definition translate to quotient space definition